# mysqlbinlog restore error 1062

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, migration

I'm having issues migrating a database from an older server to a new one. I'm first executing a dump of the old database, copying it over to the new database server and importing it. That works without any problem. But I have an issue completing the final incremental dump. I always receive a MySQL ERROR 1062 (23000) at line xxxxx: Duplicate entry '1111111' for key 'PRIMARY'. I've made several attempts with the same result. The overall database is about 40GB, not huge, but not something I can just quickly transfer over. The goal is to have minimal down time during the switch over. Unfortunately in this case we cannot just replicate to the new RDS server.

Here are the exact commands I'm executing:

- nohup mysqldump --net_buffer_length=12288 --default-character-set="utf8" --single-transaction --master-data=2 -C -q db_name -h host_name -u db_user -pdb_pass | bzip2 > backup.sql.bz2 2>&1 &
- nohup scp backup.tar.gz user@new.with.db.access.com:/files/ &
- nohup bunzip2 < backup.sql.bz2 | mysql -h new_db_host -u new_db_user -pnew_db_pass new_db_name 2>&1 &
- sudo service mysql stop (old server)
- mysqlbinlog /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.001961 --start-position=13926001 --base64-output=NEVER > output.sql (old server)
- sed -i '/SET @@session/d' output.sql (old server)
- mysql -h  -u master-username -p --one-database new_db_name < output.sql

This last command is where I'm getting the error. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you actually understand what these commands do?

Comment: I want these commands to execute without interruption so I'm using nohup for the long duration commands. I'm limiting the dump's data per insert because some tables have 10M+ rows. Saving the bin log file name and position and compressing the dump using bzip2. Then i copy it to the server that can access the new db. Decompressing and import the large dump using a single command. Stop the old DB and get an incremental dump from the binlogs given the log file and position. Deleting any lines from that file with SET @@session (due to some errors), then importing it to the given DB.

Comment: Am I miss understanding anything there?

Comment: BTW, the incremental from the bin log is only about 17MB, but it takes 30+ minutes to load (if I use the -f option to skip any of those 1062 errors). This is from an AWS EC2 m4.4xlarge on a 1TB 10,000 provisioned IOPS EBS to an AWS RDS db.r3.2xlarge DB with 1TB of 10,000 of provisioned IOPS (overkill, but it's temporary so I could load the data as quickly as possible).

Comment: *Deleting any lines from that file with SET @@session (due to some errors)* ... seems too aggressive.  What are the errors?

Comment: Without deleting SET @@session I get the error: "ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 7: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation". I'm importing the incremental using my master account for the RDS server.

Comment: What's being set to generate the error... `SET @@SESSION.xxx_what_goes_here_xxx`?

Comment: Does the old DB have to stopped in order to accurately execute the large dump? Because it's still being actively used while that dump happens, which I could see how that could cause some primary key constraint issues; however, I thought that's why the incremental is executed from the binlogs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94020/discussion-between-michael-sqlbot-and-dbl0mcjim).

Comment: I attempted the migration using replication; however, I received the same errors. On an EC2, I setup a mysql server, imported the dump from above. Set the master to the original using the binlog file and position. Start slave, then SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G; after a few minutes I get an 1062 error, duplicate key. Then Slave_SQL_Running changes to No. Any ideas? Thanks.